# How to remove a lien from Google Cloud project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google Cloud project that I want to delete.

However, when I press delete and enter the project id, I get the following error messages:

```
The project has a lien against it.

Tracking Number: {tracking number}
```

How do I delete the lien so that I can delete the project?

Thanks.

Comment: Contact Google Cloud support https://cloud.google.com/support/ or Firebase support https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: I pretty much got the same error with two tutorial projects too, I wonder when and how a lien was put on the project

Comment: you can follow: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/deprovisioning-shared-vpc#removelien

Answer (score 43):

- Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/
- Click `>-` icon beside search bar on top right corner
- The cloud shell cmd will show on the bottom
- Type `gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list` which will give you the list of liens
- Following the instruction to remove the lien

Comment: In case of dialogflow agents as liens, the instruction was to  go and delete the agent from the side. I did that, even deleted whole DialogFlow account but the error persisted. The solutoin was to delete with `gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete [LIEN_NAME]`

Comment: Select the project in the terminal (dropdown) and then list and delete the liens.

Answer (score 11):

Perform following steps as mentioned in **Google Cloud's documentation on Forcibly delete a host project** (Source: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/deprovisioning-shared-vpc#removelien):

1) Authenticate to gcloud as an IAM member who can remove a project lien. If you have [an organizational policy that limits which members can remove liens](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/provisioning-shared-vpc#protectsharedvpc), you must authenticate as an IAM member with the resourcemanager.lienModifier role for your organization. If you do not have such a policy in place, the project owner for the host project can remove the lien.

Replace `[ACCOUNT]` with the name of the appropriate IAM member:

```
gcloud auth login [ACCOUNT]
```

2) List the liens associated with the host project. Replace `[HOST_PROJECT_ID]` with the ID of the host project.

```
gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list \
--project [HOST_PROJECT_ID]
```

3) Remove each lien by name, one at a time, until no more liens are present. Replace `[LIEN_NAME]` with the name of the lien to remove.

```
gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete [LIEN_NAME] \
--project [HOST_PROJECT_ID]
```

4) Confirm that all liens have been removed.

```
gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list \
--project [HOST_PROJECT_ID]
```

5) After removing the lien, you can log out of gcloud to protect the credentials of the IAM member which has permission to remove liens.

```
gcloud auth revoke [ACCOUNT]
```

6) The host project can now be shut down.

Answer (score 5):

There is still few answers available, but none of them worked for me now, may be Google has updated its steps. I tried below and **It worked for me**

```
gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list
```

[image: You will get output like shown in below image]

Copy the lien name and run below command

```
gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete [LIEN_NAME]
```

[image]

In case you need to follow the GCP documentation [Click Here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-liens?hl=en_US&_ga=2.51741674.-2144167646.1606032727)

Answer (score 1):

The cloud shell command is:
`gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list`

From that, you will get lists or instructions on what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is the late response to the question. However, the lien doesn't always mean payment due. You might have some projects linked with it. In my case, I have integrated projects from dialog flow and Firebase in google cloud.

Once unlinked, those projects from the main cloud project I was able to delete the project from Google Cloud.

Answer (score 0):

this sounds, as if you wouldn't have paid on time; according to the definition of a `lien`:

> a right to keep possession of property belonging to another person
>
> **until a debt owed by that person is discharged**.

paying the outstanding debt is required, which would subsequently remove the lien.

until then, your project will be held hostage ...

the other answers refer to self-created liens; see [Protecting Projects from Accidental Deletion with Liens](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-liens); while in case Google's accounting has filed them, because of said reasons, you won't be able to remove them by yourself, unless complying with the invoices. you could check for the concrete `reason` why the lien had been filed, with `gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to https://console.cloud.google.com/, and click the cloud shell
   command line icon (>-) on the top right corner.
2. The cloud command line interface will show on the bottom part of
   your browser's scfreen.
3. In it type `gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list`

   It will show you a list of liens. You can see the lien name, the
   lien origin and the reason for the lien.

   For example:

```bash
NAME: p993937-l1bd-4118-4125-1002-4c0b4494j

ORIGIN: You cannot
    delete this project because it is linked with a Dialogflow agent.
    Please follow the link to Dialogflow and delete the agent:
    https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/#/agent/euioeue-ehjehjr-rjrn-rrrn/

REASON: Deletion blocked by Dialogflow.*
```

4. To delete the lien type: `gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete [LIEN_NAME]`

For example: `gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete p993937-l1bd-4118-4125-1002-4c0b4494j`

5. You have successfully deleted liens.