# I can't delete action on google project

Tags: node.js, firebase, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I have made too much projects on action on google and I thought to dekete some of these. Now, every project display me the same message:
*This project cannot be deleted because it is connected to a Dialogflow agent. Please delete the agent in Dialogflow first.*
But I have already deleted every agent that was related to the project. I have already tried on firebase but display this:
*A lien to prevent deletion was placed on the project. Remove the lien to allow deletion.*
I getting mad, please can someone help me? Thank you very much

Comment: Did you check the Google Cloud Platform (GCP console) where the project exists or not. If it exists then delete the project in GCP and then try to delete the action from Actions console

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I have already tried so and this is the problem that he says to me: "_You cannot delete this project because it is linked with a Dialogflow agent. Please follow the link to Dialogflow and delete the agent: https://console.dialogflow.com/api-client/#/agent/697a9610-fa88-4bde-b3a7-d941e430145f_". But then I go to the link and this is the response: "_Agent does not exist. IAM permission 'dialogflow.agents.get' on 'projects/697a9610-fa88-4bde-b3a7-d941e430145f' denied._".

Comment: @GiuseppeDimola Did you figure this out? I deleted my agent from https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/ but I'm still getting an error. Not sure if it's cached or something.

Comment: @Dan Leveille No, the problem is still there!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to delete mine with the help of this [Remove a lien from google cloud project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732517/remove-a-lien-from-google-cloud-project)

in particularly

```
gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list
gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete [LIEN_NAME]
```